# Translate Regex from bash to zsh

Tags: regex, bash, zsh, macos-catalina

I recently updated macOS to the new Catalina version and switched to zsh from bash as recommended.
The problem is that in my workflow we do some file operations that need regular expressions and I can't figure out how to make it work with zsh.

Here's my two regexes:

```
ls | grep ^[0-9].*.chunk.js$
ls | grep ^main.*.chunk.js$
```

They should match the following files: `main.d9a85e98.chunk.js` and `2.c2cbac0f.chunk.js`

Any ideas or resources?

Thank you!

Comment: Those should have been quoted, even with bash `ls | grep '^[0-9].*.chunk.js$'`

Comment: I recommend at least perusing `man zshexpn` and `man zshoptions` to get a feel for the kinds of differences you may see between `bash` and `zsh` as your interactive shell. `zsh` is extremely customizable; you can make it behave more similarly to `bash`, and you can make use of a *lot* of features to simplify tasks that were more difficult or impossible in `bash`.

Comment: Specifically, `zsh`'s globbing capabilities are far better than `bash`'s. In the examples you show, you could (and [should](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)) have used `ls [0-9].*.chunk.js` and `ls main.*.chunk.js` instead (especially as your regular expressions look more like patterns anyway). But `zsh` can often replace even more complicated regular expressions with glob expansion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quote the regular expression to prevent any attempts at shell expansion of the string before `grep` sees it.

```
# Ignoring the issue of parsing the output of ls
ls | grep '^[0-9].*.chunk.js$'
ls | grep '^main.*.chunk.js$'
```

---

A regular expression often can be interpreted as a shell pattern, which both `bash` and `zsh` will try to expand before running the command. 
Both shells have the option to treat a non-matching pattern as an error or as a literal string. By default, `bash` treats it as a literal string, while `zsh` treats it as an error. The "right" thing to do in either shell is to quote a string that you absolutely do *not* intend to be expanded as a pattern. `bash` just lets you get away with it more often.

In `bash`, this is controlled by the `failglob` option, which is off by default.

In `zsh`, it is controlled by the `NOMATCH` option, which is on by default.

`zsh` also has a much richer pattern language, so strings that may not have resulted in a pattern match in `bash` may do so in `zsh`. The result is the same: `grep` does not see the arguments you intended it to.

Comment: `zsh` regexes aren't relevant to the question. The issue is the shell treating a regular expression intended for `grep` as a glob before `grep` sees it.

Comment: `zsh` glob syntax isn't really relevant either, beyond knowing when it is safe to leave the regex argument unquoted. But since there's no harm in quoting it, one should probably just quote it even when strictly unnecessary.